# Object-Oriented Design - Specialization: Inheritance vs. Attributes

Tags: oop, inheritance, object-oriented-analysis

I usually come across some design problems in which I have the choice to either specialize a class by inheriting it by a sub class, or specialize the class by defining an attribute for it that classifies it. For example, for the collection of components of a car, we can either define classes (e.g. Wheel, Tire, Door ... etc), or we can define a single class "CarComponent" which have an attribute called "Type" that takes a value from an enumeration that list the different types of car components.

How can we compare those two approaches, and what design patterns would recommend each of them?

Thanks.

Comment: I think the difference in approaches would be depending on the behaviors you would need for those different classifications.

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance is about changing behaviour. If you're not changing behaviour, you have no need for a subclass. Inheritance should never be about creating a class for each noun, no matter how nice it looks.

What behaviour does CarComponent have in the context of the problem?

Then what different behaviours do Wheel, Tire, and Door have?

If they behave differently, they may be subclasses of CarComponent (but not necessarily, see below). If they don't behave differently, they're just a type.

If they do behave differently, can you accomplish the same thing with Composition? Can you move the behaviours into a Strategy?

"Prefer composition over inheritance" isn't just a slogan, it's a good idea.